# Cannot map Employee back to User ID correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My problem is: I have a `User` model , `Employee` , `Student`, `Parent`. I don't know how to map each of `Employee` , `Student`, `Parent` back to `User ID` correctly. because in the current state for example I have differentiating by a normal user and an employee (since the employee is a user as well ) , How can I do so ? For example I will paste `Employee` and `User` and `Ticket` so you can help me to map it correctly because in my system Ticket model is not dealing with the `Employee` as a `User` . please I am stuck on this two days ago :(

In those models , user_id in the ticket model is refering to creator of tickets and employee id is refering to assigned employee and thats the error i need to map Employee back to User ID correctly

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :validatable,:confirmable and :omniauthable
  devise  :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable,
          :trackable, :lockable, :timeoutable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :user_name, :first_name, :last_name, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me,
                  :role_ids, :current_password, :user_type_id
  attr_accessor :current_password
  # attr_accessible :title, :body

  has_many :assignments
  has_many :roles, :through => :assignments
  has_many :articles
  has_many :comments
  has_many :students
  has_many :guardians
  has_many :employees
  has_many :tickets
  has_many :permissions
  belongs_to :user_type
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tickets



  def has_role?(role_sym)
    roles.any? { |r| r.role_name.underscore.to_sym == role_sym }
  end
end
```

Employee.rb

```
    class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
  after_create :add_to_users

  attr_accessible :employee_number, :joining_date, :first_name, :middle_name, :last_name,
  :gender, :job_title, :employee_department_id, :qualification, :experience_detail,
  :experience_year, :experience_month, :status_description, :date_of_birth, :marital_status,
  :children_count, :father_name, :mother_name, :husband_name, :blood_group, :nationality_id,
  :home_address_line1, :home_address_line2, :home_city, :home_state, :home_pin_code,
  :office_address_line1, :office_address_line2, :office_city, :office_state, :office_pin_code,
  :office_phone1, :office_phone2, :mobile_phone, :home_phone, :email, :fax, :user_id, :school_id,
  :employee_category_id, :employee_position_id, :reporting_manager_id, :employee_grade_id,
  :office_country_id, :home_country_id

  belongs_to :employee_department
  belongs_to :employee_category
  belongs_to :employee_position
  belongs_to :employee_grade
  belongs_to :nationality, class_name: 'Country'
  belongs_to :reporting_manager, class_name: "Employee"
  belongs_to :school
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :tickets

  def add_to_users
    new_user = User.new
    new_user.user_name = self.first_name
    new_user.first_name = self.first_name
    new_user.last_name = self.last_name
    new_user.email = self.email
    new_user.password = "123456"
    new_user.password_confirmation = "123456"
    new_user.user_type_id = 2
    new_user.save
    t = Employee.find(self.id)
    t.user_id = new_user.id
    t.save
  end

  def to_label
   full_name = first_name + " " + last_name
  end

  def full_name
   full_name = first_name + " " + last_name
  end

end
```

Ticket.rb

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_save :default_values

  after_commit :close_solved
  after_commit :close_canceled

  before_create :assign_state



  attr_accessible :description, :title, :employee_department_id, :user_id, :first_name,
   :last_name , :email, :state_id, :employee_id, :ticket_state, :assign_state


  belongs_to :employee_department
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :state
  belongs_to :employee

  has_many :replies

  def default_values
    self.state_id = 3 if self.state_id.nil?
  end

  def to_label
    ticket_state.to_s
  end

  def close_solved
    if self.ticket_state == "solved"
      self.update_column(:ticket_state, "closed (solved)")
      self.save!
    end
  end

  def close_canceled
    if self.ticket_state == "canceled"
      self.update_column(:ticket_state, "closed (canceled)")
      self.save!
    end
  end

def assign_state
  if self.employee_id.nil?
    self.assign_state = "un-assigned"
  else 
    self.assign_state = "assigned"
  end 
end

  Ticket.all.each do |ticket|
    if ticket.ticket_state.blank?
      ticket.ticket_state = 'open'
    end
    ticket.save
  end

end
```

Comment: I think the best solution would be to change your schema to STI (single table inheritance). Add a column "type" to User and you can create different user types..e.g (Employee, Student, Parent). Otherwise you always have to do a workaround. With STI you always can interact with one user object and not with a strange association.. To get an idea of STI check out following links: http://www.therailworld.com/posts/18-Single-Table-Inheritance-with-Rails http://railscasts.com/episodes/394-sti-and-polymorphic-associations http://blog.thirst.co/post/14885390861/rails-single-table-inheritance

Comment: But i am using devise and cancan will i abandon the whole application ? :o

Comment: I do not know your complete application, but normally the user model is one of the foundation walls of an application. And if you always have to create a workaround, if you want to interact with an user, it is really inconvenient. I would think about that in detail. You have to sound out, if the rebuild or the workarounds are better for you. But that is just my opinion and I do not know your whole application architecture..

Comment: in the recent time there no other solution ?

Comment: I do not have a solution, but can´t you change your has_many :employees, :students.. to has_one associations?

Comment: what about the Ticket model is there a way to make it deals with employee and user both as a current user ?

Comment: also my application i guess it will not be good with STI because its not a small app

Comment: STI has nothing to do with application size.

Comment: I can't risk now by using STI I never used it before i don't know what I have to do when I change to it, is it just copy and paste into a new file and let every thing like it was ? my deadline is 20/9 :( and did not finish the first task yet :(

Comment: could you tell me what is the point of making the relation has_one instead of has_many ?

Comment: why not use ticket.employee.user ?

Comment: @Mattherick , It does . we can use STI only when we can share common table schema for all inherited  models