# Filter index for CanCan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan, wice-grid

I am trying to filter the index according to the ability. I am using the [wice_grid](http://rubygems.org/gems/wice_grid) gem to make a table in the index, and to add a condition to tickets, we could use something called [:conditions](https://github.com/leikind/wice_grid#conditions).

I have tried to put it like that:

```
@tickets_grid = initialize_grid(Ticket,
                                :include => [:user, :employee_department, :state],
                                :conditions => [Ticket.accessible_by(current_ability)])
```

This is not working, though. I'm looking for any suggestions.

Update: `:conditions` is working like `ActiveRecord` so I guess I need a query to look up through roles and detect the current ability

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is current_ability.model_adapter(Ticket, :index).conditions where Ticket is your model and :index is your access type.

so in your case it should be:

```
@tickets_grid = initialize_grid(Ticket,:include => [:user, :employee_department, :state],:conditions => current_ability.model_adapter(Ticket, :index).conditions)
```

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Fetching-Records

Answer (score 0):

From the section of the documentation you linked to:

> Alternatively, instead of a Class object as the first parameter, you
>   can use ActiveRecord::Relation:
>
> ```
> @tasks_grid = initialize_grid(Task.where(:archived => false, :projects => {:active => true}).joins(:project) )
> ```

`Ticket.accessible_by(current_ability)` is a relation, not a hash of conditions, so you would do `initialize_grid(Ticket.accessible_by(current_ability))`.  But you should already have `@tickets` initialized by CanCan, so you just need to `initialize_grid(@tickets)`.

Comment: did not work , i guess thats because wice grid is not accepting `@tickets`

Comment: i guess its should be in :conditions , you said its a relation so i need a condition (because conditions like an active record ) to make it look through the database fields , i am using the separate role model , users has many roles thorugh assignments